# "Error: unknown shorthand flag: 'n' in -nstances" when trying to connect Google Cloud Proxy to Postgresql (Django)

Tags: django, postgresql, google-cloud-sql

I'm following a google tutorial to set up Django on Cloud Run with Postgresql connected via Google Cloud Proxy. However I keep hitting an error on this command in the Google Cloud Shell.

cloud shell input:
xyz@cloudshell:~ (project-xyz)$ ./cloud-sql-proxy -instances="amz-reporting-files-21:us-west1-c:api-20230212"=tcp:5432

returns:
Error: unknown shorthand flag: 'n' in -nstances=amz-reporting-files-21:us-west1-c:Iamz-ads-api-20230212=tcp:5432
Usage:
cloud-sql-proxy INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME... [flags]

Flags:
-a, --address string                       (*) Address to bind Cloud SQL instance listeners. (default "127.0.0.1")
--admin-port string                    Port for localhost-only admin server (default "9091")
-i, --auto-iam-authn                       (*) Enables Automatic IAM Authentication for all instances
-c, --credentials-file string              Use service account key file as a source of IAM credentials.
--debug                                Enable the admin server on localhost
--disable-metrics                      Disable Cloud Monitoring integration (used with --telemetry-project)
--disable-traces                       Disable Cloud Trace integration (used with --telemetry-project)
--fuse string                          Mount a directory at the path using FUSE to access Cloud SQL instances.
--fuse-tmp-dir string                  Temp dir for Unix sockets created with FUSE (default "/tmp/csql-tmp")
-g, --gcloud-auth                          Use gcloud's user credentials as a source of IAM credentials.
--health-check                         Enables health check endpoints /startup, /liveness, and /readiness on localhost.
-h, --help                                 Display help information for cloud-sql-proxy
--http-address string                  Address for Prometheus and health check server (default "localhost")
--http-port string                     Port for Prometheus and health check server (default "9090")
--impersonate-service-account string   Comma separated list of service accounts to impersonate. Last value
is the target account.
-j, --json-credentials string              Use service account key JSON as a source of IAM credentials.
--max-connections uint                 Limit the number of connections. Default is no limit.
--max-sigterm-delay duration           Maximum number of seconds to wait for connections to close after receiving a TERM signal.
-p, --port int                             (*) Initial port for listeners. Subsequent listeners increment from this value.
--private-ip                           (*) Connect to the private ip address for all instances
--prometheus                           Enable Prometheus HTTP endpoint /metrics on localhost
--prometheus-namespace string          Use the provided Prometheus namespace for metrics
--quiet                                Log error messages only
--quota-project string                 Specifies the project to use for Cloud SQL Admin API quota tracking.
The IAM principal must have the "serviceusage.services.use" permission
for the given project. See https://cloud.google.com/service-usage/docs/overview and
https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/requester-pays
--sqladmin-api-endpoint string         API endpoint for all Cloud SQL Admin API requests. (default: https://sqladmin.googleapis.com)
-l, --structured-logs                      Enable structured logging with LogEntry format
--telemetry-prefix string              Prefix for Cloud Monitoring metrics.
--telemetry-project string             Enable Cloud Monitoring and Cloud Trace with the provided project ID.
--telemetry-sample-rate int            Set the Cloud Trace sample rate. A smaller number means more traces. (default 10000)
-t, --token string                         Use bearer token as a source of IAM credentials.
-u, --unix-socket string                   (*) Enables Unix sockets for all listeners with the provided directory.
--user-agent string                    Space separated list of additional user agents, e.g. cloud-sql-proxy-operator/0.0.1
-v, --version                              Print the cloud-sql-proxy version

While my input is "-instances" the error message returns "-nstances" as if it's either truncating somehow, or as if it's matching my input to the "-i" flag inadvertently.

I've tried shortening my project name to avoid truncating, and tried inputting the command inside a yaml file instead of running it in google cloud shell.

Comment: The `-instances` flag is not a supported flag for the v2 version of the Cloud SQL Auth Proxy, it is still part of the v1 proxy which may be causing the confusion. Please see the [latest documentation](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-sql-proxy#basic-usage) for use of the v2 proxy.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like `-instances` is not a valid flag for Cloud SQL Proxy tool and hence the error.

Remove that flag, something like below should work.

`./cloud-sql-proxy amz-reporting-files-21:us-west1-c:api-20230212 -p 5432`

Please refer to the supported flags [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qT7gP.png).

This is using the latest cloud-sql-proxy version [2.0.0](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-sql-proxy#:%7E:text=cloud%2Dsql%2Dproxy-,Linux%20386,-%23%20see%20Releases).

Comment: Exactly right. We recently shipped a (much-improved) v2 where you can just specify your instance connection name directly without any flags.

Comment: Thank you Gourav B! For others trying this tutorial https://cloud.google.com/python/django/run please know that it's out of date regarding version of cloud sql proxy